# Tracking users on moodle course

Tags: php, moodle

Can anybody tell me is there some plugin for tracking users on course?

I need to know which user is on which point or finish what tests to know when he come to final test and get final certificate on some course. Is that possible and how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's mostly accessed in the Moodle menu.

To see who completed which test, go to Navigation > Reports > Activity completion

(Make sure Activity completion is turned on of course!)

Let me know if it isn't. You can turn it on in Settings > Site Admin > Enable activity completion

Which version of Moodle are you using?

Comment: I am using moodle 2.x. and I just find this on Site administration-> Courses-> Course default settings. Tnx.